# Why is my SSF file opening in Pathfinder Office in read only mode?

Tags: gps

I have a new SSF file that I just copied from my Trimble GeoExplorer 2008 series GPS unit to my desktop.  I also copied the shapefiles from the unit.

When I double-click on the SSF file, I receive the following error.

```
Changes cannot be made to this file as it was created with GPSCorrect. 
The file has been opened in read only mode.
```

It never actually opens a file though.  I need to be able to run a correction on it and then apply the correction to the shapefile that the data was collected for.

Answer (score 0):

If this is still a problem 10 months later:  What do you mean by "It never actually opens a file though"?  Do you mean you don't see any features in PathFinder Office?  That would be normal, because the SSF file saved by GPSCorrect doesn't have any feature information, ESRI applications stored that in some other files.  The GPSCorrect SSF file contains positions and GPS raw measurements etc which can be used for post-processing.  You can confirm that the file can be opened and contains information by right-clicking on the SSF file in File Explorer and selecting "Edit", which opens the file using SSF Record Editor.

You can correct the file by right-clicking on the SSF file and selecting "Correct" but I'm sure that's not the normal process for post-processing it - there must be some better-integrated work-flow when using ESRI Applications with GPSCorrect but I can't remember it!